# How to get Scilab 6.0.0 working on Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: java, scilab

On my Ubuntu 17.10 system I downloaded Scilab 6.0.0 from official site, extracted it and tried to launch:

```
wget http://www.scilab.org/download/6.0.0/scilab-6.0.0.bin.linux-x86_64.tar.gz
tar -xzf scilab-6.0.0.bin.linux-x86_64.tar.gz
cd scilab-6.0.0
bin/scilab
```

But it does not launch:

```
$ bin/scilab
Cannot find this look and feel:
[GTK look and feel - com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel] not supported on this platform
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

If I try to specify fallback Motif look and feel manually I get crash again:

```
$ _JAVA_OPTIONS='-Dswing.installedlafs=com.sun.java.swing.plaf.motif.MotifLookAndFeel' \
bin/scilab
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dswing.installedlafs=com.sun.java.swing.plaf.motif.MotifLookAndFeel
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

It crashes on both Xorg and Wayland.
What else should I try to get it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you backtrack to an earlier version and install the scilab 5.5 package from the default Ubuntu 17.10 repositories. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install scilab
```

In April when Ubuntu 18.04 is released, you can upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04 and get scilab 6.0 back again.

Comment: Forgot to mention, 5.5.2 from repositories works normally with any look-and-feel. But 6.0.0 binary from scilab.org crashes.

Comment: I looked in the Scilab repos online so I know that 5.5.2 is the most common version now, but maybe bionic will get it sorted so that Scilab 6.0.0 stops crashing.

Comment: What is interesting - scilab *6.0.0-1* from *universe* repository on 18.04 LTS works normally. But version from `scilab-6.0.0.bin.linux-x86_64.tar.gz` crashes. So Scilab maintainers from Debian and/or Ubuntu did their work very good.

Comment: Package management sucks on daily builds however.